# Gtk3 themes look wrong/corrupted

Tags: themes, gtk

I recently lost access to my account due to a loss of permissions (for example .ICEauthority was owned by root). When I fixed everything, I recovered access to my account, but the gtk3 themes that i had previously installed (and were working properly) are now full of missing textures, and bugs. I have tried installing them again, with no success. Only the default themes are shown as intended, but the ones I added (like arc, dark-aurora, or yosembiance) have this problem. I have also tried deleting `/home/user/.config/gtk-3.0/` with no success neither.

I'll include a screenshot so you can see what i'm talking about:

[image: corrupted gtk screenshot]

Comment: You should mention that what exactly happened and what did you've done to fix it otherwise we can't help you ;)

Comment: What is wrong ? I do not understand the problem from that picture.

Comment: I think it was a problem with chrome remote dekstop, which changed some permissions

Comment: The terminal shouldn't have a white background, the corners of the apps should be round, the ON-OFF switcher is invisible, etc etc. The dark aurora theme should look like this: https://www.google.es/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj_163_4tbTAhXGDxoKHStICCQQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DUqZO1Iw2_Xo&psig=AFQjCNG9wZODFymdNCy9Ydf5oeMJZmlSHw&ust=1494005643432401